Como quitarle el style display none desde javascript a un botón
Tengo un botón con el id reset. El botón en mi archivo css tiene estos estilos
  #reset{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #d3ef1b;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
  }

El problema esta que cuando quiero quitarle el estilo display none desde mi js es como si fuera que no lo quita, el botón sigue con display none.
Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma en el js document.getElementById("reset").style.display="";
Me he fijado en el id del botón y esta bien. Si alguien puede ayudarme por favor.

Reemplaza la cadena vacia por 'block', 'inline', 'inline-block' o cualquier otro valor que display... supuestamente el valor 'initial' vuelve a colocar el valor por defecto del elemento para la propiedad 'display', pero nunca lo he probado.

Una cadena vacía no es un valor valido para la propiedad display
Si lo que buscas es que tome el display default de un button, puedes utilizar unset, que reestablece la propiedad a su valor heredado (si es que hereda) de lo contrario coloca el valor "default"
display: unset;

o en javsacript
document.getElementById("reset").style.display="unset";

